# RabbitMQ transactions are commiting without exceptions while queue is down

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to send message from publisher to broker synchronically, via transaction, as described [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/) (Guaranteed Delivery with Tx) in order to get guaranteed message delivery from publisher to broker.

So i send messages to broker.

```
        try
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() {HostName = "localhost"};
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: routingKey, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                properties.Persistent = true;

                channel.TxSelect();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    channel.BasicPublish("", routingKey, properties, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("nop"));
                    channel.TxCommit();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

What I expect is that message will be delivered to broker and persisted to queue. Or exception will occur if something go wrong.

But when I delete queue while messages are publishing nothing happens.

Why transaction is committed without any exception?

Answer (score 2):

From referenced code and article I don't see where would it fall with exception.

For exception you would need TxSelect to process something. But as you won't get anything new in queue it won't have anything to work on. Thus no exception from it. 
On the other hand I'd guess publish just get you Task, a promise that per your code seem just stay unprocessed as such. Again - no exception.

I would recommend to do same thing without creating a queue. 
Quite sure there would be no exception either.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you check TxCommit for return value?

https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v1.7.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-1.7.0/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#txCommit()

> Returns:
>   a transaction-commit method to indicate the transaction was successfully committed

Comment: Yes, it's java realization. For C# it's void.